# Ruby - Random Number is the Same Random Number, Every Time

Tags: ruby, random

```
wordList = ['1930', '1931', '1932', '1933', '1934', '1935', '1936', '1937', '1938',        '1939', '1940']
wordLen = wordList.length
wordRand = rand(wordLen)
year = wordList[wordRand]
```

Very much a newb here... The behavior of `year` is such that every time I run the program, it selects a random string from `wordList`. The problem is that it takes that particular randomly-selected number and sets it as equal to `year`. So, for every instance of the program, `year` is the same string from the list each time I call it. How can I get it to select a different number each time?

```
puts 'Why hello there, dear! Grandma is, SO, happy to see you!'
response = gets.chomp
  while response != 'BYE'
    if response == response.upcase
      puts 'NO, NOT SINCE ' + year + '!'
      response = gets.chomp
    else
      puts 'WHAT? SPEAK UP, SONNY!'
      response = gets.chomp
    end
  end
  if response == 'BYE'
    puts 'OKAY, BYE DEAR!!'
  end
```

edit: added context

Comment: No it is not.. for me

Comment: Hmm... okay let me show you the context:

Comment: The code above works fine.  The code below references the variable `year`, so if you rerun the code below, year will not change.  Is that your problem?  If so, you need to make the code above into a method `year()` (i.e., `def year() ... end`).  Note, one Ruby convention is for all letters in variable (and method) names to be lowercase, with underscores inserted for readability.  Camel-case (`LikeThis`) is reserved for class and module names.

Comment: As you are new to SO, you may want to review the forum guidelines for [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Nothing wrong with your choice here, though in future you may want to wait a little longer, lest you discourage other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to only be generating one value for `year`, then repeatedly using it in your loop.  If you want different numbers, put the call to `rand` within the loop.